# $W$ boson recontruction

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

How we can reconstruct the $W$ boson, when decays leptonically because there is MET ($W$-->lepton+neutrino). Need a theoretical description in detail. Can any one explain this?

Comment: In simple enough events you can reconstruct the recoiling initial system. As long as there is only a single particle missing conservation of (transverse) momentum gallops in to save the reconstruction. What I don't know (never having done collider physics) is what statistical methods are using to obtain a sample that is rich in single missing particles.

Comment: Did you try the CERN document server http://cds.cern.ch/?ln=en? CERN has an enormous amount of material online about high energy physics (theory and phenomenology) and the detector technology/analysis algorithms. There should be more than enough in there to find what you are looking for, you may have to spend some time digging, though. Look for "W Z reconstruction".

Comment: See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/9712029 who do just that

Answer (score 0):

W and Z reconstruction can be said happens when there is an excess in certain particles. These particles could be usually tauons and tauon neutrinos. Depending on whether it is a W boson or Z boson leptons or quarks are created. However quark number and lepton number are conserved so one antimatter particle and one particle is created.

Comment: It really depends on particles are seen more in the collider, that is how reconstruction of particles in particle accelerators work.